# Python: import scipy leads to traceback referencing a deleted file

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When I try to import the scipy module (version 0.11.0b1) in the Python interpreter (version 2.6.1), I receive the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in module

File "/Users/...long path.../Desktop/scipy-0.11.0b1/scipy/\__init__.py", line 114, in module

ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
    being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
    tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.
```

---

The problem is that python is reading from a file that doesn't exist. I deleted the scipy directory from my Desktop a while ago and have since tried restarting the interpreter (and the computer) several times. Why does the traceback continue to refer to a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: Probably you need to delete some package related information under `python/site-packages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the python path is including a reference to the directory you deleted.

If you:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

You should be able to see a reference in there to the deleted directory. If that's the case, removing that entry from sys.path will allow you to import scipy as before.

The tricky part may be finding *where* that path is being injected into sys.path. Possible locations include (but aren't limited to): your system's site.py file, the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or even your O/S `PATH` environment variable.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

Add the scipy path as show below.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

include_files = ['C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy']

setup(name = "ventana",
      options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':include_files}},
      version = "0.1",
      description = "ventana",
      executables = [Executable("REC.py")],)
```