# Python - Error importing Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have seen some solution for handling this problem but I have not been successful to resolve it yet. Can one of you tell me what to do step by step?

What I can do for exiting the SciPy source?

BTW, I couldn't install SciPy by pip or easy_install. I have downloaded it and add the it's folder in the libraries.

```
ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
    being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
    tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.
```

[edit]
solution like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069309/python-import-scipy-leads-to-traceback-referencing-a-deleted-file) .
 i am using python 2.7 . on windows 7.

also i have seen the way to install MinGw before installing scipy by pip or easy_install. i have tried but nothing changed.

[edit 2][sorry for bad explanation]

this is what happen when I use easy_install

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Best match: scipy 0.14.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/scipy-0.14.0.zip#md5
=7ee4fa9e756bab6b46b79f77c821cb68
Processing scipy-0.14.0.zip
Writing c:\users\sali\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dqnk8b\scipy-0.14.0\setup.
cfg
Running scipy-0.14.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\sali\appdata\loca
l\temp\easy_install-dqnk8b\scipy-0.14.0\egg-dist-tmp-nuhhkg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64 is invali
d.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/intel64 is i
nvalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:576: UserWarning: S
pecified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
error:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

Comment: Did you run Python from the command line (Terminal.app, "DOS prompt", etc.)? If so, quit Python, then `cd` to anywhere else. If not, tell us how you launched it and hopefully we can help, but there are too many possibilities to just guess at.

Comment: But meanwhile, if you can't install it, you can't use it. You have to solve that problem.

Comment: Also, vague information like "I have seen some solution but I have not been successful" is not only not helpful, it's actively harmful. If people have no idea which solutions you've seen, they may just assume that whatever they were going to suggest, you already tried it, and not bother. Tell us exactly what solutions you've tried (ideally with links), and exactly what went wrong.

Comment: i add the folder of scipy in liabrary , is  it ok ? is the version of numpy realated to the version of scipy i intalled ?

Comment: @abarnert , i edit the question . if u can help ?

Comment: @user3075338: You still haven't told us what happened when you did `pip install scipy` or `easy_install scipy`. Did you get errors? If so, post the errors, and someone can help you. No one can help you with just "I can't make it work" because that's not enough information, and no one can help you use scipy without installing it because that's not possible.

Comment: @abarnert  I edit again . sorry for inconvenient

Comment: One last comment: Don't tack "\[edit\]" sections onto the end of your question. Edit the main body of the question into something readable and useful, so anyone who might be able to help you can immediately tell what help you need, and anyone with a similar problem can immediately tell that it's a similar problem. (If anyone really cares about the past versions of your question, SO maintains an edit history.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you copied the source folder for scipy into your Python path somewhere. That won't work, since scipy needs to be compiled; you'll have to install it, either via `python setup.py install` from the source directory, `pip`/`easy_install`, or with [a binary installer](http://www.scipy.org/install.html).

Comment: I am quite beginner in coding and deal with this stuff ,so ,maybe my question sounds silly. I have run setup.py file from the main folder if you mean this. if not , can you clarify please?

Comment: Yes - you ran `python setup.py install`? If it didn't print out any error messages, that should mean it got installed properly. Where did you out the directory you ran it from?

Comment: after downloading the scipy file , i run this file through the scipy folder ==> setup.py . which shows a command prompt page and close it after writing some stuff ! sorry if i am not good at explaning . and i do not know if i get what you mean. I edit the question about what it showed using easy_install to install it.thanks

Comment: You need to run `setup.py install` from the command line, not just double-click or whatever on `setup.py`. But you'll get the same errors as with pip/easy_install, because you're missing a dependency library (BLAS). Use the binary installer linked by @bananafish or use the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) python distribution.

Comment: when I write " import scipy" in IDLE , it said =>No module named scipy. that means it is not installed ,right?

Comment: The binary installer is the simplest way. Download a `.exe`, execute it, and be done.

Comment: @user3075338 yes, `import scipy` is the way to use it. Once it is installed (so you can import it), you can make sure it is working as it should running `scipy.test()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, install libraries using the binaries provided [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). I have a 100% success rate with packages from this site that fail when I try to use `pip` (usually the problem is the C compile step for packages that use C extensions).

Comment: how can I install a file using pip?

Comment: @user3075338: Install pip from the binary provided at the link in the answer. Add `c:\python27\scripts` to your system `path`. At a dos prompt, install with `pip install <package>`. But it won't work for scipy - use the binaries provided at the linked site instead.

Comment: is it like :pip install [-r/-e] file address ?

Comment: @user3075338 No, it is just `pip install <package>`. For example `pip install scipy` (which won't work on Windows). Nothing else needs to be downloaded, and it gets installed into your Python folder.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of warnings, but only one error:

```
error:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

Most likely, the problem is that you haven't installed BLAS. (If you have, then the error message tells you exactly how to fix the problem.)

Some Python packages require non-Python (C) libraries to build them. The Python package `lxml` requires `libxml2`. And `scipy` requires all kinds of things, including BLAS. There's no way `pip` or `easy_install` can fix these problems for you.

So, how can you figure out what to do? Read the [install documentation](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) for the package. If you don't know where it is, just Google "scipy install", or go to the SciPy front page, and you will find it.

In a few cases—and SciPy is one of them—the prerequisites are so onerous that the package maintainers will suggest you don't even try unless you really know what you're doing. When you read the install documentation I linked above, their first suggestion is that you throw out your current Python and get an extra-batteries-included build of Python like Anaconda or Enthought that comes with the full SciPy stack ready to go. They next tell you how to find pre-built binaries of the full stack for most platforms (but not Windows). Then they tell you how to find pre-built binaries for specific parts of the stack (for Windows, that's [Christoph Gohkle's archive](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)). If you actually want to build from source (with `pip` or otherwise), you have to click through to each of the separate pieces of the stack and read a whole new page of install instructions for each one.

So, at this point, if you still want to try installing with `pip`, you should know what your next steps are; if not, you should know what your alternatives are.